# UITableViewCell being formatted to default size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've programmed UITableViews before a few times. I really can't see whats wrong with what I'm doing. I am adding UILabels to the view, but I think they're added with the size relative to the default UITableView cell size is. When I omit heightForRowAt, the top and bottom text of the view is at about the top and bottom of the cell, so I think that something is happening with the heightForRowAt function and the height isn't being passed to my subclass. Also, I'm setting the text alignment to be right on the right sided labels and that isn't working either.

[Here is what my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmwm.png)

[When I don't implement heightForRowAt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEjow.png)

I'll post the important type pieces of code here as well. Maybe theres an issue I'm not seeing.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    let tblViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    tableView = UITableView(frame: tblViewFrame, style: .plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(FeedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: feedCellID)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: feedCellID, for: indexPath)
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //not going to be this big, just for testing
        return CGFloat(100)
}
```

Also I'm pretty sure my CGRect math is correct because I redid it a bunch of ways and it never worked. For the UITableViewCell I added a UIView as a subview with the text all inside of that. Any help would be appreciated

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FeedViewCell:UITableViewCell {

    var titleLabel:UILabel!
    var subtitleLabel:UILabel!
    var topRightLabel:UILabel!
    var bottomRightLabel:UILabel!
    var innerView:UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style:style, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
        formatCell()
    }

    func formatCell() {
        backgroundColor = colorSet.sideViewBackgroundColor
        createLabels()
        formatLabels()
        print(frame.height)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func formatLabels() {
        //titleLabel
        titleLabel.text = "Top Left"
        titleLabel.font = fontSet.feedViewTitleFont

        //subtitleLabel
        subtitleLabel.text = "Bottom Left"

        //topRightLabel
        topRightLabel.text = "Top Right"
        topRightLabel.textAlignment = .right

        //bottomRightLabel
        bottomRightLabel.text = "Bot Right"
        bottomRightLabel.textAlignment = .right
    }

    func createLabels() {

        //Space so stuff doesn't touch edges
        let bufferSpace = CGFloat(0)

        let horDelim = self.frame.width * CGFloat(0.75)
        let verDelim = self.frame.height * CGFloat(0.5)

        let tlRect = CGRect(x: bufferSpace, y: bufferSpace, width: horDelim - bufferSpace, height: verDelim - bufferSpace)
        let trRect = CGRect(x: horDelim, y: bufferSpace, width: self.frame.width - horDelim - bufferSpace, height: self.frame.height - verDelim - bufferSpace)
        let blRect = CGRect(x: bufferSpace, y: verDelim, width: horDelim - bufferSpace, height: self.frame.height - verDelim - bufferSpace)
        let brRect = CGRect(x: horDelim, y: verDelim, width: self.frame.width - horDelim - bufferSpace, height: self.frame.height - verDelim - bufferSpace)

        innerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))

        titleLabel = UILabel(frame: tlRect)
        subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: blRect)
        topRightLabel = UILabel(frame: trRect)
        bottomRightLabel = UILabel(frame: brRect)

        innerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        innerView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        innerView.addSubview(topRightLabel)
        innerView.addSubview(bottomRightLabel)
        addSubview(innerView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `FeedViewCell` class so we can see how the cell's contents is being laid out? Are you doing it manually or using auto layout? If you are using auto layout, have your tried setting the `UITableView`'s `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for dynamic sizing?

Comment: @DennisW. Added the `FeedViewCell` code. I tried it before without putting the labels inside the inner uiview and the same thing happened. I'm trying to tdo the automatic dimension thing but I can't seem to find it. On the docs it says its a global variable. Is it like `UITableView.UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or `CGFloat.UITableViewAutomaticDimension`? Can't seem to access the value.

Comment: In older Swift versions it was `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, now I think it might  be `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

Comment: @DennisW. Yeah that didn't fix it.

Comment: You cannot use `UITableView.automaticDimension` unless you are using auto layout, and from a first glance it looks like the cell is being laid out manually.

Comment: Yeah I'm laying it out on my own. I set `heightForRowAt` to return 100, but in the initializer to the `FeedViewCell` I printed out the `frame.height` and it showed 44, which is probably the default. Its weird because the cell height is generated in the image, but the contents don't seem to be aware of it. I can't do much because I'm getting the view out of the `cellForRowAt` method which is a black box to me and then it comes out with the wrong height. Thank you for you help

Comment: A couple of points on laying the cell out manually, you should add your custom content to the cell's `contentView` property, not the cell itself. Also the frame logic needs to go in `layoutSubviews`. This will get called when the device orientation changes and you will get the correct frame width. You will need to calculate the height of your labels manually, based on their content. There should be old examples around, since this was the way before auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might go about laying out the cell manually. For each content view you would need to determine the content's height and width, and calculate their alignment relative to the other items in the cell. This is a simplistic example since the labels are not multiline and I just arbitrarily made each content view half the cell's width.

You would also need to set the cell's size in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. In the past before auto layout worked with collection views, I used a sizing cell (a static instance of the cell) where I could pass in the cells content and then get the height for the cell based on the content it would be displaying.

```
import UIKit

class FeedViewCell:UITableViewCell {

    var titleLabel:UILabel!
    var subtitleLabel:UILabel!
    var topRightLabel:UILabel!
    var bottomRightLabel:UILabel!
    var innerView:UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style:style, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
        formatCell()
    }

    func formatCell() {
        createLabels()
        formatLabels()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func formatLabels() {
        //titleLabel
        titleLabel.text = "Top Left"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan

        //subtitleLabel
        subtitleLabel.text = "Bottom Left"
        subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = .orange

        //topRightLabel
        topRightLabel.text = "Top Right"
        topRightLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        topRightLabel.textAlignment = .right
        topRightLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow

        //bottomRightLabel
        bottomRightLabel.text = "Bottom Right"
        bottomRightLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        bottomRightLabel.textAlignment = .right
        bottomRightLabel.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    func createLabels() {
        //Space so stuff doesn't touch edges
        titleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        topRightLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        bottomRightLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(topRightLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(bottomRightLabel)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        /* title label */
        let marginSpacing:CGFloat = 5
        let itemSpacing:CGFloat = 5

        var width = frame.width * 0.5
        var height = calculateTextHeight(width: width, text: titleLabel.text!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: titleLabel.font!])
        let titleRect = CGRect(x: marginSpacing, y: 8, width: width, height: height)

        /* subtitle label */
        width = titleRect.width
        height = calculateTextHeight(width: width, text: subtitleLabel.text!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: subtitleLabel.font!])
        let subtitleRect = CGRect(x: marginSpacing, y: titleRect.maxY + itemSpacing, width: width , height: height)

        /* top right label */
        width = frame.width - titleRect.width - marginSpacing
        height = calculateTextHeight(width: width, text: topRightLabel.text!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: topRightLabel.font!])
        let topRightRect = CGRect(x: titleRect.width, y: titleRect.origin.y, width: width, height: height)

        /* bottom right label */
         width = frame.width - subtitleRect.width - marginSpacing
        height = calculateTextHeight(width: width, text: bottomRightLabel.text!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: bottomRightLabel.font!])
        let bottomRightRect = CGRect(x: subtitleRect.width, y: topRightRect.maxY + itemSpacing, width: width, height: height)

        titleLabel.frame =  titleRect
        subtitleLabel.frame = subtitleRect
        topRightLabel.frame = topRightRect
        bottomRightLabel.frame = bottomRightRect
        print("maxY", bottomRightLabel.frame.maxY)
    }

    func calculateTextHeight(width:CGFloat, text:String, attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key:UIFont]) -> CGFloat {
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let labelRect = text.boundingRect(with: size, options:[.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes:attributes, context: nil)
        let height = ceil(labelRect.height)
        return height
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }
}
```